# why Request.QueryString replace + with empty char in some cases?

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I have a problem that if I pass a string that contain `+` in a query string and try to read it , it get the same string but by replacing + with empty char
For example if i pass query like `../Page.aspx?data=sdf1+sdf` then in page load I read `data` by `data = Request.QueryString["data"]` it will get as below  `data ="sdf1 sdf"`
I solve the problem by replacing any empty char with `+` ..

**But Is there any problem that cause that ? and Is my solution by replacing empty char with + is the best solution in all cases ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `+` is the url encoded representation of space `" "`. If you want to preseve the plus sign in your value you will need to url encode it:

```
"/Page.aspx?data=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("sdf1+sdf")
```

which will produce:

```
/Page.aspx?data=sdf1%2bsdf
```

Now when you read `Request.QueryString["data"]` you will get what you expect.