# Request Object not picking up all characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, request

I am stumped on this scenario. Basically I have an URL that is passed to a aspx page and then I try to get query string from the URL, but what happens is when I try to get the query string from the URL it omits the '+' and replaces it with an whitespace.

```
My URL =  http://localhost:3872/Test.aspx?mt=jan1TNIixxA1+8tl/0vLLg2PPGq0vMOLEhFQNuG4AJU12VMZpnWTrgar82K5UlXatQT9E9EAUet+q7rq7FoTJf+S2JnSbIptgJDY1EZwRPJDTROktfu5zy25oydmSHB6a4oZetV5mI3s+0R7vW8I0S9d765RHdYU2xkRuojHYZU=

Request["mt"] =jan1TNIixxA1 8tl/0vLLg2PPGq0vMOLEhFQNuG4AJU12VMZpnWTrgar82K5UlXatQT9E9EAUet q7rq7FoTJf S2JnSbIptgJDY1EZwRPJDTROktfu5zy25oydmSHB6a4oZetV5mI3s 0R7vW8I0S9d765RHdYU2xkRuojHYZU=
```

As you can see these two strings are different.

I thought it was the object to string conversion but this does not seem to be the case cause the value of the object has the omitted '+' before conversion.

What can be done to avoid this character replacement (I want to try and avoid string manipulation)

Also what could the cause of this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are getting that because `+` is the url encoded representation of space `" "`. If you want to preseve the plus sign in your value you will need to url encode it:

Send that querystring in URL encoded formate and then you will get the expected result.

see: [why Request.QueryString replace + with empty char in some cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356829/why-request-querystring-replace-with-empty-char-in-some-cases)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
MyUrl = MyUrl.Replace("+",@"%2B");
```

The problem is the '+' character is being converted to whitespace if you use httprequest. If you convert it to its hex value, you can pass it with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) to generate you parameter value. Currently it seems you are using base64 encoding which is not optimal for query parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
mt=encodeURIComponent(mt);//if mt be --> jan1TNIixxA1+8tl/0vLLg2PPGq0vMOLEhFQNuG4AJU12VMZpnWTrgar82K5UlXatQT9E9EAUet+q7rq7FoTJf+S2JnSbIptgJDY1EZwRPJDTROktfu5zy25oydmSHB6a4oZetV5mI3s+0R7vW8I0S9d765RHdYU2xkRuojHYZU=
Response.Redirect("Test.aspx?"+mt);
```

this will encode your URL and after this '+' will converted to "%2B" and if you want to read encoded URL it will not converted to space.

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7867626/2040375)

Answer (score 1):

If it is **really** so important to avoid changing the string when you send it, you could chanhe it AFTER you get ir from httprequest. Maybe you could use:

```
MyUrl = (Request["mt"].Replace(" ","+"));
```

There is no possibility to pass the space in url, so when you have a space, you can be sure that there was a '+' in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the query string using following method

```
string strQuery =  Request.Url.Query;
```

Comment: How will this work with multiple query strings. Again I want to try and avoid string manipulation.

Comment: What do you mean to say Multiple Query String ??